# Missing PHP environment setting to read in variables from require call

Tags: php, debugging, environment

Consider the following third party code:

```
$methodParams = [];
$modules = array_diff(scandir('modules'), array('..', '.'));


foreach ($modules as $module) {
    require_once 'modules/' . $module;

    if (isset($methodList))
        $methodParams = array_merge($methodParams, $methodList);
}
```

In the production environment (PHP 5.6.30), the array `$method_params` gets filled from `$methodList` arrays defined in `modules/$module` files.

However, in a test environment (PHP 5.6.37) the array `$method_params` remains empty.

Why and how to debug?

Comment: Have you check if `$modules` is getting the right data?

Comment: @ntzz indeed, these were two slightly different versions of the software, i.e. a method defined at the production site was not defined in the code in the testing environment.m Thanks! I.e. my problem is not yet solved but I have now solved another important problem. Will check then later.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks for the clarification.